# SharePoint 2013 alerts working on random users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm running into an issue with SharePoint 2013 alerts. We have our team discussions list with alerts set up for multiple users and several of them are not receiving the emails. Here's what i've done for troubleshooting:

1. SMTP configured properly
2. CA email configured
3. timer server running
4. have not upgraded/migrated SP to a newer version
5. Checked permissions - for this testing all users are setup as owners of the list.
6. Confirmed users email addresses are correct

I'm i missing anything?

Comment: How do you implemented this, is it through workflow or default out of box alerts feature of SharePoint ?

Comment: Out of the box alerts. I was able to figure out the issue - Our DEV environment was pointing to our legacy SMTP server. i updated it and all users started getting the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this to trouble shoot the SharePoint Alerts

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

Comment: Thank you Suresh - This is one of the articles i went through.

Answer (score 0):

Our DEV environment was pointing to our legacy SMTP server. i updated it and all users started getting the alerts.

Here are the links i used to troubleshoot my issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html